# TypeScript error when mocking UseSelector callback function

Tags: typescript, react-redux, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock UseSelector to create some tests of a hook and the mock looks like this:

```
const mockUseSelector = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-redux", () => ({
  useSelector: (callback) => mockUseSelector(callback)
}))
```

However, I'm receiving the following typescript warning:

`Parameter 'callback' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`

I know that I can type it directly on its declaration or use //@ts-ignore, but is there any way to avoid this error when creating this kind of mock? E.g, in a config file?

I looked for an `d.ts` file, or a global config, but I didn't find any solution.

Update: Here's the hook that I'm testing:

```js
import { MEALS } from "../../data/dummy-data";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../hooks/redux";
import { selectMealsIds } from "../../store/redux/slices/favorites";

export function useFavoritesScreen() {
  const favoriteMealsIds = useAppSelector(selectMealsIds);

  const favoriteMeals = MEALS.filter((meal) =>
    favoriteMealsIds.includes(meal.id),
  );

  return {
    favoriteMeals,
  };
}
```

And here's the test file:

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-native";

import { useFavoritesScreen } from "../Favorites.hook";

import { DUMMY_DATA } from "./fixture";

const mockAppState = {
  favorites: {
    ids: ["m1"],
  },
};

const mockUseSelector = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-redux", () => ({
  //@ts-ignore
  useSelector: (callback) => mockUseSelector(callback),
}));

describe("screens/favorites/useFavoritesScreen", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("returns favorite meals when ids are provided", () => {
    mockUseSelector.mockImplementation((callback) => callback(mockAppState));
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFavoritesScreen());

    expect(mockUseSelector).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(result.current.favoriteMeals).toEqual(DUMMY_DATA);
  });
});
```

P.S: `useAppSelector` is just a useSelector typed as the documentation suggests: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript

Comment: So is it just that `callback` needs to be explicitly typed? What is its type, or what are you passing it when unit testing? Do you even need to mock the `useSelector` hook (*I suspect probably not*), but I don't know what you are trying to do here. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?